# How to split a row into many equals rows by a value in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008-r2, union

There is any way to dismember a row into many rows by a value into row column?
Doing my query, i got the result:

```
ID TmpShoppingCart_ID StoreSKU_ID QuantityΞΞ Enabled 
26 34                 448         2          True 
27 34                 3465        4          True 
28 34                 3468        1          True
```

But I want:

```
ID TmpShoppingCart_ID StoreSKU_ID QuantityΞΞ Enabled 
26 34                 448         1          True 
26 34                 448         1          True 
27 34                 3465        1          True 
27 34                 3465        1          True 
27 34                 3465        1          True 
27 34                 3465        1          True 
28 34                 3468        1          True
```

There is any simple sintax to do that?

Comment: So what is your query?

Comment: SELECT [ID]
      ,[tmpShoppingCart_ID]
      ,[StoreSKU_ID]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Enabled]
  FROM [proveagora.com_new].[dbo].[tmpShoppingCartItem]
  where tmpShoppingCart_ID = 34

Comment: Why have you tagged `Linq` if you don't use it?

Comment: Yes, I can use it. I'm trying right now the Repeat, but i got an error and i'm trying to solve this:

Message = "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[proveagora.Domains.Models.tmpShoppingCartItem] Repeat[tmpShoppingCartItem](proveagora.Domains.Models.tmpShoppingCartItem, Int32)', that cannot be converted into an expression

Comment: You have not even mentioned Linq-To-Entities. I've deleted my answer since that is not supported in L2Entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more option with the master..spt_values system table. Also you can replace the system table on the own sequence table

```
SELECT ID, TmpShoppingCart_ID, StoreSKU_ID, o.Quantity, [Enabled]
FROM [dbo].[tmpShoppingCartItem] t 
CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT 1
             FROM master..spt_values v
             WHERE v.type = 'P' AND v.number < t.Quantity
             )o(Quantity)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec4c2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate numbers in SQL Server using a recursive CTE.  Once you have a list of numbers, you can do the query.

Here is an example with 100 as the maximum:

```
with nums as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n < 100
     ),
     t as (select 26 as id, 34 as TmpShoppingCart_id, 448 as storesku_id, 2 as quantity, 'true' as enabled)
select id, TmpShoppingCart_id, storesku_id, 1, enabled
from t join
     nums
     on nums.n <= t.quantity;
```

If that is not big enough, you can make it dynamic, but have to pay attention to the MAX_RECURSION option:

```
with t as (
      select 26 as id, 34 as TmpShoppingCart_id, 448 as storesku_id, 200 as quantity, 'true' as enabled
     ),
     nums as (
      select 1 as n, MAX(quantity) as maxq
      from t
      union all
      select n + 1, maxq
      from nums
      where n <= maxq
     )
select id, TmpShoppingCart_id, storesku_id, 1, enabled
from t join
     nums
     on nums.n <= t.quantity
option (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this simple enough?

```
begin transaction
declare @rowcount int
set @rowcount = 1

while @rowcount > 0 
begin

    insert into shoppingcart(tmpShoppingCart_id,StoreSKU_Id,Quantity,Enabled)
    select tmShoppingCart_id,StoreSku_id,1,enabled
    from shoppingcart where quantity > 1

    update shoppingcart
    set quantity = quantity - 1
    where quantity > 1

    select @rowcount = @@rowcount

end
commit transaction
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I did not a good explanation. I cant change the values in database. I need a query wich show me the current values in a diferent way.